# How to launch Internet Explorer from the command prompt?

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer

I have to launch Internet Explorer from the DOS command prompt.

I have done it with Firefox, like:

```
cd \program files\mozilla firefox\
firefox
```

How to do the same with Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 27):

Just type

```
c:\windows\servicepackfiles\i386\iexplore.exe
```

You can also use

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Comment: will this also work with the command line from windows (cmd) ? Cuz' it does not for me..

Comment: @TheChange - My original post of just typing "iexplore.exe" doesn't work on the command line - sorry about that ... it works from START -> RUN ... the "c:\windows\servicepackfiles\i386\iexplore.exe" should work from the DOS prompt (cmd).

Comment: there is no "servicepackfiles" folder in my windows folder here (on work) and the IE is in program Files folder - maybe this is a country-related thing or something? (iam from germany) just interested :)

btw. typing iexplore in Start->Run works

Comment: Thanks scott... can you tell one more thing??? 

i have to open command prompt, but my laptop is not starting, when i on it, it show a error.. BOOTMGR is compressed restart press ctrl+alt+dlt.

i have to open dos and launch ieand then delete some file from c drive

Comment: @TheChange - Just noticed that ... seems windows (US version) has a couple of iexplore.exe versions, very odd to say the least. I updated my post to include "C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" ... I am hoping that is a common install point (even in the german/european version of windows)

Comment: @ankush ... I'm not sure what is happening with your laptop unfortunately. Maybe posting your question to serverfault.com will get an answer for the BOOTMGR issue you're having? good luck !

Comment: @Scott Vercuski - this also depends on the windows version I think (as always :-( ).  
Dunno why one would need to open the IE to deinstall a file (Iam confused)

Answer (score 19):

Though you're asking for Internet Explorer: just in case you want to use the *default* browser, then use the [`start`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx) command:

```
start "" "http://superuser.com"
```

Comment: Maybe without the quotes, but I cannot test right now. Community wikified just to be sure.

Comment: @grawity, smart solution!

Comment: The first quotes are necessary like since Windows 7. This is why you'll find pages saying `start "http://example.com"` works no more.

Comment: Quotes are needed cuz they represent window title. I tried to fill it and never see the name over the cmd window... Glad to now that now is mandatory... ho ho ho manadatory empty strings.

Comment: You can leave off the first pair of quotes if you leave off the second pair;  i.e., you can say `start https://superuser.com`.

Answer (score 19):

You should cut its location to its original location, "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\", and then you can start it by using:

```
start iexplore
```

Comment: THIS is the most short answer. Question says Internet Explorer. Using Start "" "URL" will invoque your primary/favorite browser.
This is also correct: "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" and compatible between OS's also for 64bit versions.

Comment: you can also pass the URL on the command line: `start iexplore https://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 5):

From anywhere:

```
start iexplore
```

ought to do the trick - actual path is unimportant. As long as the path exists - it'll run the executable. As a note: `start firefox` should work as well under a default installation.

If you want to run things without the path environment variable set - it's pretty easy to create a registry launch alias: http://commandwindows.com/runline.htm

Answer (score 4):

There should be an environment variable for the *Program Files* directory. On my install it is `%ProgramFiles%`. It may be localized for a given language into whatever the equivalent phrase/word is in that language. I could imagine that the *Internet Explorer* folder name might be localized as well. This should handle cases where Windows is installed to a drive letter other than C:

Thus, to start Internet Explorer from the command line (for me):

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Remember the double quotes as there is a space in the command line!

Comment: Using variables %ProgramFiles% is a good way to avoid path mistakes also made compatible script between 32/64 os paths. Anyway `start iexplore` looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I use it:

```
iexplore "http://superuser.com/questions/113345/how-to-launch-internet-explorer-from-the-command-prompt"
```

Result:  Opens IE and navigates to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to open internet explorer in the command prompt is by simply typing `start iexplore.exe`. You can also use the same  method to open Chrome as well.

Don't forget to open command prompt in elevated mode.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to use start with exe name as 1º param.

1. `start "" iexplore` // you may use `start iexplore` on most systems.
2. `start "" firefox`
3. `start "" chrome`

Yes! works.

But you have ask only about IExplorer. Following your code sample: 
`cd \program files\mozilla firefox\
firefox`

Same code with internet explorer equals to:
`cd \program files\internet explorer\
iexplore`

When `start iexplorer` do not work for you, the best chance may be:
"%programfiles%\internet explorer\iexplore" // you do not need to use uppercases

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your internet Explorer system folder files are located, the following opens up the yahoo main page for instance as it is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http:\yahoo.com"

Answer (score 0):

To force internet explorer to be used try this:

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" -new "https://www.google.com"

After several attempts, i found that you must type  -new   in between the iexplore and website.  Hope this helps.

Comment: What does ``-new`` do? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.